# Azure Storage SDK v10 Java 11 support

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is the Azure storage v10 SDK and its dependencies compatible with Java 11?
 Didn’t see a reference to Java 11 in the following:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Did not find reference or statement in this [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) as same as you. I downloaded jar package for `Blob Storage SDK v10` from the [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage-blob/10.3.0) and decompress it. I check the `Build-Jdk` property is `1.8.0_181` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Based on the Oracle official document : [Security Baselines JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11all-relnotes-5013287.html). The baseline version for V8 is `1.8.0_191-b12` which is upper than above version.

However, I tested `Blob Storage SDK v10` code locally with `V11` JDK and it works fine.I suggest you taking a shot on your side. Also,you could [commit feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to azure storage team.

Answer (score 0):

You will need javafx, which is not provided by java 11.The dependency is used for instance in TransferManager - not that it really uses functionality of javafx, it is just introduced by an apparently lazy programmer..